# Unite/join Database and Eloquent's model query in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, orm

I have to check if an user is online (in-game), and if he's not then do another checks to perform a sql update.

Actually, I have these two queries.

```
$isOnline = DB::connection('mssql')->table('USER_STAT')->where('user_id', $userID)->value('ConnectionStat');
$character = Character::where('acc_id', $userID)->where('Name', $characterName)->firstOrFail();
```

Is there a way I can use `union` or `join` in order to save a DB query? I believe this is not a good practice, and some better method is out there, which I can't find in the docs.

I tried something like this, but without success:

```
$character = Character::where('acc_id', $userID)->where('Name', $characterName)->firstOrFail();
$result = DB::connection('mssql')->table('USER_STAT')->where('user_id', $userID)->union($character)->get();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to update the `ConnectionStat`?

Comment: @chasenyc no, I just need to know if he's online... ConnectionStat should return either 0 (offline) or 1 (online).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a relation in your Character Model to the Model of the USER_STAT table you can easily lookup the things you need to determine if an update somewhere is needed.

[Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

This does not consolidate the queries into one, like with a join, but they are not heavy anyway, and using the ORM to the fullest will have more significant advantages in the long run.

If you think you must use an SQL-join you must stick to the querybuilder, but the ORM is usually the better choice

[Query Builder Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins)

Comment: Thank you! I'm newbie so I'm having problems with Models too... Are you telling me that I should create a `ConnectStatModel.php` and attach it to the user model? What kind of relationship should I use for them having in mind the database structure?

Comment: I would make a UserStat Model, and in the Character Model make a relation to that

`public function stat()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserStat', 'user_id', 'acc_id');
    }`

if acc_id is set as $primaryKey in the Character Model you can leave that out
get your $character with the relation loaded
and access all related stats easily

`$character = Character::with('stat')->where('acc_id', $userID)->where('Name', $characterName)->firstOrFail();
    $isOnline = $character->stat->ConnectionStat;`